# Sitecore Express Migration tool compatibility for 8.1 and 8.2

Tags: express-migration-tool

I want to migrate Sitecore 8.1 and 8.2 Initial version to 9.0 Initial version.
Can I use Express Migration Tool for this upgrade? If yes then which version?

Comment: If you can upgrade to Sitecore 9.1, I would recommend using update package directly -> https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/91/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_91_Initial_Release.aspx

Comment: Ok but i wanted to evaluate whether i can do it by SEM as it would be faster approach. In compatibility table i do not see 8.1 & 8.2 in source does it mean SEM doesn't support these versions?

Comment: Express Migration tool doesn't support migration from 8.X to 9.X so you should use the update package and that's the fastest & safest way comparing with any other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On newer versions like 8.1 and 8.2 you do not need the migration tool. The upgrade package can take you directly there in one step.

This is a change from earlier versions of Sitecore where you would have to do step by step for each version using update packages.